# Calculating linear speed of a dough hook stand mixer.

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametrization, arc-length

EDIT: After sitting on this and digesting a bit with the comments, I realized I really want both the maximum and minimum speeds. The selected issue should get me there.

I'm trying to calculate the effective linear speed of the dough hook arm of a stand mixer, such as a KitchenAid mixer. If I can figure out the arc length I think I can get the speed easily enough. I also suspect that polar coordinates would help solve this, but it has been way too long since I've had to use polar coordinates and I can't even remember how to set this up.

Below is a quick schematic of how I'm looking at this problem. We have a dough hook attachment which is basically a stick on an “arm” of length "r" (70 mm in my case). This arm is then attached to a larger “ARM” with radius "R". ARM rotates at a given speed (approximately 45 revolutions per minute).  For each complete revolution of ARM, arm rotates X times (say 2.5 times). If I am looking at point B, for one complete revolution of ARM, how far has B traveled through space? Or how fast is B moving through space, but if I can get the distance, I can use RPM to get speed easily enough.

Thank you all for the help! Let me know if you need more information or if I asked this in the wrong way. If I missed an answer that already provided this information, chances are I just didn't understand the terminology well enough to realize it was the same question.

---

**TLDR**:
See schematic below, point “*B*” is orbiting around another revolving point “*A*”. A orbits around a fixed point in space with radius “*R*”, and *B* orbits around  *A* with a radius of “*r*”. For  each complete revolution of *A*, *B* completes “*X*” orbits. How do I calculate the arc length (and speed) of *B* with respect to the center of *A*’s orbit?

For example numbers assume: *R* = 250 mm, *r* = 50 mm, *X* = 2.5

A rough schematic of the dough hook traveling around the bowl of the mixer, with the circular arc of point *A* in the center, and two possible arcs for point *B* on the right.

[image: A rough schematic of the dough hook traveling around the bowl of the mixer, with the circular arc of point A in the center, and two possible arcs for point B on the right.]

Comment: The speed of B is not constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity vector of point $A$ relative to axis over one period is
$$(R\omega_R\cos(\omega_Rt),R\omega_R\sin(\omega_Rt)).$$
Now, for simplicity assume that points $A$ and $B$ start their travels with the same phase.  Then, the velocity of point $B$ relative to point $A$ is
$$(r\omega_r\cos(\omega_rt),r\omega_r\sin(\omega_rt)).$$
Then, total velocity vector of point $B$ relative to axis of mixer is
$$v = (R\omega_R\cos(\omega_Rt)+r\omega_r\cos(\omega_rt),R\omega_R\sin(\omega_Rt)+r\omega_r\sin(\omega_rt)).$$
Speed at any time $t$ is given by
$$s(t) = \sqrt{(R\omega_R\cos(\omega_Rt)+r\omega_r\cos(\omega_rt))^2+(R\omega_R\sin(\omega_Rt)+r\omega_r\sin(\omega_rt))^2}.$$

Total distance travelled over one cycle is
$$D = \int_{0}^{T} s(t)dt.$$

Formula for $\omega_R$:  Time how long it takes for point $A$ to make one revolution, say $T_A$.  Then, $\omega_R = 2\pi/T_A$.

Formula for $\omega_r$:  Count how many loops during rotation, say $n$.  Then,
$\omega_r = n\omega_R$.

Finally, if you are trying to calculate "effective" linear speed, I assume that you want and average speed in some sense.  One way to do this is simply compute $s_{eff} = D/T$ using formulas above.